# Find the largest $n \in \mathbb{N_+} $ such that $\{ (2+\sqrt 2)^n\} < \frac{7}{8}$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

#### Problem

Find the largest $n \in \mathbb{N_+} $ such that $\{ \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^n\} < \dfrac{7}{8}$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x.$

#### My Solution

First, we can prove that $a_n=(2+\sqrt{2})^n+(2-\sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer sequence. For this purpose, we may apply the mathematical induction. However,in fact,by setting up the characteristic equation $x^2-4x+2=0$，we may confirm that the equality above of $a_n$ really gives the general term formula of the recursion sequence as follows $$a_1=2,a_2=12,a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-2a_{n}(n=1,2,\cdots).$$ Now, it's clear that $a_n$ are a series of integers. Moreover, notice that $0<(2-\sqrt{2})^n<1.$ We can obtain  $\{(2+\sqrt{2})^n\}=1-(2-\sqrt{2})^n.$ Thus, the problem is to ask us to find the largest $n \in \mathbb{N_+}$ such that
$$\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^n<8.$$ But the left side increases with the increasing $n$. Hence, we only need to test the critical value.

Since $$2^{3/4}=\sqrt{2 \cdot \sqrt{2}}<\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}<\frac{2+2}{2}=2,$$ we have $\left(\dfrac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^4>2^3=8$, and $\left(\dfrac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^3<2^3=8.$ As a result, the largest $n$ is $3$.

*Please correct me if I'm wrong! And I hope to see another new solution. Thanks!*

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newer here. So I'm not familiar to the rules of the website. Thanks for your reminding. @GNU Supporter

Comment: Your use of AGM to get $2^{3/4}\lt{2+\sqrt2\over2}$ so that you can test the inequality for $n=4$ without doing a bunch of computation is really nice. Well done!

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This approach is great. However, it is a bit confusing when you use the fact that $$\color{#C00}{\frac1{\left(2-\sqrt2\right)^n}=}\left(\frac{2+\sqrt2}2\right)^n\lt8$$ It might improve clarity to include something like the red part above

Comment: However，I think it to be obvious.Since that $(2+\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt{2})=2^2-(\sqrt{2})^2=2,$ hence $ \dfrac{1}{2-\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Note that

$$
(2+\sqrt 2)^n = a_n+\sqrt 2 b_n\\
(2+\sqrt 2)^{n+1} = a_{n+1}+\sqrt 2 b_{n+1}
$$

then

$$
a_{n+1} = 2(a_n+b_n)\\
b_{n+1} = a_n + 2 b_n
$$

with $a_1 = 2, b_1 = 1$

NOTE

As far as I understood, I am afraid that the problem has no solution because

$$
\{(2+\sqrt 2)^n\} = \{\sqrt 2 b_n\}
$$

Suppose now we have a $n = n^*$ such that $\{\sqrt 2 b_n\}\lt\frac{7}{8}$ The sequence of $b_n$ follow without limit an then surely will appear another $n^{**}$ that will achieve that.